# How to mock according to the number of invocations of method using java and Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, code-coverage

I have a method that returns the quantity of rows of something like a log.

So if I call the first time, returns 0 rows. But if I call one more time, it could return one or more rows.

```
someList = getLogLines("unique-id");
```

Another method has a logic related to the quantity of rows of the first method.

```
initialRows = getLogLines("unique-id");
if(initialRows.size()==0){
  //some logic
}
//another lines and logic
newRows = getLogLines("unique-id");
if(newRows.size()>0){
  //another logic
}
```

As you can see `getLogLines("unique-id")` is called several times with the same argument `"unique-id"`.

On unit test, How can I mock **getLogLines** to receive a result according to the **number of invocations** with the same argument?

If each invocation would have different arguments, it would be easy to mock

```
doReturn(emptyRows).when(Foo).getLogLines("bar-id");
doReturn(severalRows).when(Foo).getLogLines("baz-id");
```

But I cannot find how to mock different result when the argument is the same.

I only found `Mockito.times(x)` but I cannot find how to combine **verify** and **doReturn**:

- [Counting method invocations in Unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694992/counting-method-invocations-in-unit-tests)
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/unit-testing/mockito/verifying-varing-number-of-invocations.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698670/6650475) should help.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it works as expected. I will mark this question as duplicated